# Limited CRS options of GeoServer WMS

Tags: geoserver, wms, getcapabilities

I am trying to limit the list of available CRS for the WMS GetCapabilities of a single workspace to reduce the size of resulting XML for parsing on the front-end app side. I have found the Limited SRS list option in the WMS admin interface, added the following: 4326, 3857

This makes the change valid when going to: `...geoserver/wms?request=GetCapabilities&...`

result is:

```
<!-- Limited list of EPSG projections: -->
<CRS>EPSG:4326</CRS>
<CRS>EPSG:3857</CRS>
<CRS>CRS:84</CRS>
```

But both GetCapabilities of a single workspace or a single layer do not respect that.

Going to `...geoserver/wstest/test/wms?request=GetCapabilities&...`
I can really see the two CRS as the options of that particular layer,

```
<Layer queryable="1" opaque="1"> 
    <Name>test</Name>
    <Title>test</Title>
    <Abstract/>
    <KeywordList>
        <Keyword>test</Keyword>
        <Keyword>WCS</Keyword>
        <Keyword>ImageMosaic</Keyword>
    </KeywordList> 
    <CRS>EPSG:3857</CRS>
    <CRS>CRS:84</CRS>
```

but I still also receive the basic full list of the WMS service itself.

```
<Layer> 
    <Title>GeoServer Web Map Service</Title>
    <Abstract> A compliant  implementation of WMS plus most of the SLD extension (dynamic styling). Can also generate PDF, SVG, KML, GeoRSS </Abstract>
    <!-- All supported EPSG projections: --> 
    <CRS>AUTO:42001</CRS>
    <CRS>AUTO:42002</CRS>
    <CRS>AUTO:42003</CRS>
    <CRS>AUTO:42004</CRS>
```

Etc...

Should this change not be sufficient to remove the additional CRS from the resulting XML, or is there a way to propagate this change to the workspace/layer GetCapabilities response separately that I missed?

Comment: see this thread from the user list - https://sourceforge.net/p/geoserver/mailman/message/36450466/

Comment: Sorry for double post! That is my post. I am not on the user-list and the only email that I received back was that the post is waiting for moderator for being approved. I should have received that it was approved already, but I did not. Anyway no response in the thread yet.

Comment: may be you need to join the mailing list so you see the discussion - checkout [this talk (or video)](http://www.ianturton.com/talks/foss4g.html#/) to see how to seek help with opensource software

Comment: Sorry again. Unfortunately I can not see any messages inside this thread even after registering to sourceforge and joining the mailing list. Just my post and that's all. Probably linked to the fact, that I was sending the message from "outside" of the mailing list, however that is not related to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can not see the possible response on the mailing list, I will post an answer here just in case.

I just missed the small drop-down list with workspace selection on top of the WMS settings page. This changes the SRS output of the GetCapabilities response for the workspace and all layers inside it.