# Geoserver's WMS GetCapabilities request takes too long to respond

Tags: coordinate-system, geoserver, wms, getcapabilities

I have about 300 vector and 30 raster layers in a GeoServer instance (version 2.7.4) and when the client makes a WMS GetCapabilites request, it takes about 3 minutes to receive the response. 
The vector layers are stored in a PostGIS database while raster layers are stored as GeoTIFF files.

In the field: Limited SRS list of WMS admin page, I have imported the SRSs that I'm using like:

```
4326, 3857, 2100
```

and the result of list in WMS GetCapabilities file is:

```
<!--Limited list of EPSG projections:-->
  <SRS>EPSG:4326</SRS>
  <SRS>EPSG:3857</SRS>
  <SRS>EPSG:2100</SRS>
```

Nevertheless, the request takes too long to response. I found a similar question:
[Limited CRS options of GeoServer WMS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/300595/limited-crs-options-of-geoserver-wms)

In the answer, @lubojr says the following: "I just missed the small drop-down list with workspace selection on top of the WMS settings page"

I also selected the corresponding workspace in that dropdown menu but the result was the same.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: where is the data stored? Oracle DB? Which version of GeoServer are you using?

Comment: For vector layers I'm using PostGIS while the raster layers are stored as GeoTIFF files. I'm using 2.7.4 version of GeoServer.

Comment: please use the edit button to modify your question, also please upgrade to a recent 2.13+ version of GeoServer.

Comment: I'm using GeoServer as part of a GeoNode instance, so I think that I would have problems if I upgrade GeoServer without upgrading Geonode. Is there a way to solve the issue without an upgrade ?

Comment: Almost certainly no, you need to upgrade to get the benefit of the fixes and speed up of the last 5 years.